# Multiple Users Logged In Causing Incorrect Account Returned

Tags: plugin-development, users, login

I have a plugin that I have written that has a front-end login and I have had reports by multiple users that state that when they login (presumably at the same time???), they see someone else's profile in my plugin.  How does authentication work in WordPress?  I am using the WordPress function `wp_signon` and passing it credentials.  By using this method, does it not create a cookie locally to determine your user session?  Or is this all handled on the server?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If I cannot figure this out, my plugin will be a complete failure.

**UPDATE:**
Including some code as I've had more reports that if multiple users are using the same wireless router (at the same location), that one person clicks on our "dashboard" and as the next person clicks the menu option to visit the dashboard, they are automatically logged in as the previous user.  Only code I have running is the following:

```
function user_dashboard_shortcode()
{
    global $current_user;
    $memberid = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix.SSM_TEAMMEMBER_TABLE . " WHERE user_id = " . $current_user->ID); 
    echo "<h3>Team Member Info</h3>";
    echo "Current User ID: " . $memberid;
}
```

Now, the output on the page is the same ID for two users (one right after another).

Comment: can you post your code here to figure out where is the problem.

Comment: updated and included my code.  I have removed my custom login and solely rely on the built-in WordPress login and it still happens, so I'm assuming it's something wrong with my shortcode or something